# Did Stephen Miller ever publicly discuss his support for antisemitic organizations?

Tags: united-states, antisemitism, alt-right

Recently [leaked emails](https://www.splcenter.org/hatewatch/2019/11/12/stephen-millers-affinity-white-nationalism-revealed-leaked-emails) show that [Stephen Miller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Miller_(political_advisor)) systematically supports and cooperates with groups on the extreme right which [promote antisemitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDARE).

Did he ever publicly discuss this cooperation with organizations and individuals to whom he and his family are potential targets?

Answer (score 6):

Stephen Miller has not (yet) admitted to even having produced those emails, so asking for his rationalization of antisemitism is a bit premature.

However, one need only look at his background to see what kind of person he is. Miller grew up in Santa Monica, one of the most highly-educated and liberal cities in America, and the son of two dyed-in-the-wool rich Jewish liberal Democrats. His political activism started in middle school when he read 'Guns, Crime and Freedom' by NRA CEO Wayne LaPierre as a rebellion against his parents, city, and state, all of whom are anti-gun.

He is a prototype of the alt-Right movement: rich, smart, educated, and yet totally isolated from even a hint of adversity growing up but wanting something to rebel against. Classmates in high school say he enjoyed riling up his liberal and nonwhite classmates with controversial statements and compelled Latinx classmates to 'speak only English'. He wrote a letter to the editor at age 16 condemning his high school's (inclusivist) response to September 11th, stating that "Osama bin Laden would feel very welcome at Santa Monica High School". This is a guy that never evolved beyond the adrenaline rush of trolling people in middle school and has turned it into an extremely successful career.

Comment: Let's, for the sake of argument, not dispute anything you say in tone or substance -- the ideological overlap with the alt-right/supremacist cluster is obvious in any case. (Perhaps I should add to my question that I'm aware of that.) Then I'm still puzzled that the antisemitism of the supremacists is not a show-stopper. There is certainly a sane Republican core whose members are adamantly anti-immigration but not antisemitic. In fact, being pro-Israel is a hallmark of Republican falcons. Why not side with them? Just because they are not in power? Pure opportunism? It seems more than that.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Opportunism is a helluva drug. The religious Republicans are getting Roe v. Wade overturned. The pro-business Republicans are getting entire portions of government dissolved or de-toothed. If you're a one- or two-issue voter, Miller's policies are getting a lot of stuff done.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica There is also a strong strain of "I'm in the in-group *enough*" to many exclusionist ideologies (frequently; I assert nothing in this specific case). It's entirely possible for person A to consider themselves "white" and Jewish both, but for person B to conclude that the latter excludes person A from the former group. It is a mistake to assume strong, internally consistent, sequential logic applies to any prejudice, let alone to all individuals that associate with groups that identify with that prejudice, or that the criteria for exclusion are stable over time.